# Cron criandos arquivos no servidor

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

Tenho os comandos:

```
curl https://meusite.com/acesso/cron/cotacoes
wget https://meusite.com/acesso/cron/CPTEC
```

Ele executa esses dois comandos que são responsáveis por salvar algumas fotos no servidor, o problema é que além dele salvar as fotos (eles salvam as fotos na pasta correta) eles estão criando arquivos na pasta **'/'** com o final da **URL.NUMERO**, como por exemplo:

```
cotacoes.01
CPTEC.01
```

O problema é que não sei o porque eles estão criando, pois não coloquei nenhum comando para cria-ló. Se for o caso e mais fácil poderia até ficar salvando, mas na pasta **/estacoes/**

Como posso arrumar isso? Precisava que ele parasse de gerar esses arquivos ou pelo menor indicar uma pasta para ele salvar para ficar organizado.

Answer (score 1):

Para determinar um diretório aonde os arquivos serão salvos, com `wget` basta informar o parâmetro `-O`, ex:

```
# Salva na raiz
wget https://meusite.com/acesso/cron/CPTEC -O /
# Salva em um subdiretório
wget https://meusite.com/acesso/cron/CPTEC -O /estacoes/
```

`curl` basta informar o parâmetro `-o`, note que o parâmetro aqui é minusculo, ex:

```
# Salva na raiz
curl -o / https://meusite.com/acesso/cron/cotacoes
# Salva em um subdiretório
curl -o /cotacoes/ https://meusite.com/acesso/cron/cotacoes
```

Note que em `CURL` primeiro você informa o local aonde será salvo e depois a *URL*, já no *Wget* vem a *URL* depois o local aonde será salvo.